# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Roll"

Tags: java, eclipse

Okay, so I am pretty new to programming and I am exploring what I can do so far. I wrote a code for what looks like the start of a game. My goal is to have the computer ask 3 different users their name and ask them to type in the word "Roll" to have a random number assigned to them. Then I want the computer to check which number is the highest to see who will go first and so on. When I run the code, the code works up until the point where it's supposed to check which number is the highest. I have written this so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class apples{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
Random order = new Random();
String n1;
String n2;
String n3;
String a1;
String a2;
String a3;
System.out.println("Enter the name of the first player: ");
n1 = name.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the name of the second player: ");
n2 = name.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the name of the third player: ");
n3 = name.nextLine();
System.out.println(n1+ " type 'Roll' for your number: ");
a1 = name.nextLine();
if(a1.equals("Roll")){
String player1 =String.valueOf(1+order.nextInt(10));
System.out.println(player1);
}else{
System.out.println("Please type in Roll.");
  }
  System.out.println(n2+ " type 'Roll' for your number: ");
  a2 = name.nextLine();
  if(a2.equals("Roll")){
  String player2 =String.valueOf(1+order.nextInt(10));
  System.out.println(player2);
}else{
  System.out.println("Please type in Roll.");
    }
    System.out.println(n3+ " type 'Roll' for your number: ");
    a3 = name.nextLine();
    if(a3.equals("Roll")){
    String player3 =String.valueOf(1+order.nextInt(10));
    System.out.println(player3);
  }else{
    System.out.println("Please type in Roll.");
  }

int num1 = Integer.parseInt(a1);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(a2);
int num3 = Integer.parseInt(a3);
  if(num1>num2 && num1>num3){
    System.out.println(n1+" You will go first.");
  }else{
    if(num2>num1 && num2>num3){
      System.out.println(n2+" You will go first.");
    }else{
      if(num3>num1 && num3>num2){
        System.out.println(n3+" You will go first");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error message I am receiving is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input     string: "Roll"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at apples.main(apples.java:44)
```

I have tried to change the strings a1,a2,a3 to player1,player2,player3 and see if that works but then it says that player1 cannot be resolved to a variable.
Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Please format your code. It is nigh-on impossible to follow as it stands.

Comment: basically you are just trying to convert "Roll" into an integer....

Comment: The "int num1 = Integer.parseInt(a1)" is parsing a String into an Int. and it doesn't like this. Maybe assign them random numbers from 3? Then that will randomly pick the order.

Something like...

    int num1 = Math.random() * 4
    int num2 = Math.random() * 4
    int num3 = Math.random() * 4

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is triggered by the following sequence:

```
int num1 = Integer.parseInt(a1);
int num2 = Integer.parseInt(a2);
int num3 = Integer.parseInt(a3);
```

You are trying to convert a String to an Integer, which isnt possible, except your String contains only numbers.

In your case, your Strings look like this:

```
a1 = "Roll"
a2 = "Roll"
a3 = "Roll"
```

I think that this arent the correct values you want to work with. You want to work with the input you get via:

```
player1 = String.valueOf(1 + order.nextInt(10));


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class apples {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random order = new Random();
        String player1 = null;
        String player2 = null;
        String player3 = null;
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the first player: ");
        String n1 = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the second player: ");
        String n2 = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the third player: ");
        String n3 = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println(n1 + " type 'Roll' for your number: ");
        String a1 = name.nextLine();
        if (a1.equals("Roll")) {
            player1 = String.valueOf(1 + order.nextInt(10));
            System.out.println(player1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please type in Roll.");
            player1 = "0";
        }
        System.out.println(n2 + " type 'Roll' for your number: ");
        String a2 = name.nextLine();
        if (a2.equals("Roll")) {
            player2 = String.valueOf(1 + order.nextInt(10));
            System.out.println(player2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please type in Roll.");
            player2 = "0";
        }
        System.out.println(n3 + " type 'Roll' for your number: ");
        String a3 = name.nextLine();
        if (a3.equals("Roll")) {
            player3 = String.valueOf(1 + order.nextInt(10));
            System.out.println(player3);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please type in Roll.");
            player3 = "0";
        }
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(player1);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(player2);
        int num3 = Integer.parseInt(player3);
        if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3) {
            System.out.println(n1 + " You will go first.");
        } else {
            if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3) {
                System.out.println(n2 + " You will go first.");
            } else {
                if (num3 > num1 && num3 > num2) {
                    System.out.println(n3 + " You will go first");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just a little tip: To avoid converting your generated numbers from a String to an Integer, cast them as Integers directly, like:

```
int numberPlayerOne;
.......
.......
numberPlayerOne = 1 + order.nextInt(10);
```

When you want to parse the generated numbers directly to Integers, use this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class apples {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random order = new Random();
        int numberPlayerOne = 0;
        int numberPlayerTwo = 0;
        int numberPlayerThree = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the first player: ");
        String n1 = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the second player: ");
        String n2 = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the third player: ");
        String n3 = name.nextLine();
        System.out.println(n1 + " type 'Roll' for your number: ");
        String a1 = name.nextLine();
        if (a1.equals("Roll")) {
            numberPlayerOne = 1 + order.nextInt(10);
            System.out.println(numberPlayerOne);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please type in Roll.");
        }
        System.out.println(n2 + " type 'Roll' for your number: ");
        String a2 = name.nextLine();
        if (a2.equals("Roll")) {
            numberPlayerTwo = 1 + order.nextInt(10);
            System.out.println(numberPlayerTwo);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please type in Roll.");
        }
        System.out.println(n3 + " type 'Roll' for your number: ");
        String a3 = name.nextLine();
        if (a3.equals("Roll")) {
            numberPlayerThree = 1 + order.nextInt(10);
            System.out.println(numberPlayerThree);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please type in Roll.");
        }
        if (numberPlayerOne > numberPlayerTwo && numberPlayerOne > numberPlayerThree) {
            System.out.println(n1 + " You will go first.");
        } else {
            if (numberPlayerTwo > numberPlayerOne && numberPlayerTwo > numberPlayerThree) {
                System.out.println(n2 + " You will go first.");
            } else {
                if (numberPlayerThree > numberPlayerOne && numberPlayerThree > numberPlayerTwo) {
                    System.out.println(n3 + " You will go first");
                }
            }
        }
    }

 }
```